# Reading CSV file as a key value pair

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, file

I have a CSV file as mentioned below.
CSV file content :

| NAME | SURNAME | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shri | siri | 23 |
| Golu | Kumar | 25 |

I need to read this CSV file as a key value pair.

[{'NAME':'Shri', 'Surname':'siri', 'Age':'23'}]

[{'NAME':'Golu', 'Surname':'Kumar', 'Age':'25'}]

Comment: NAME,SURNAME,AGE -> 1st column    
Shri,siri,23                      -> 2nd column                       Golu,Kumar,25              -> 3rd column

Comment: Do you need a dictionary per row afterwards? Pandas .to_dict() might be what you're looking for: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `records` argument

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

Or to get output as the one you provided

```
df1 = df.to_dict('records')
_list =[]

for i in range(len(df1)):
   _list.append(df1[i])

_list
```